# Jasmine mock object in test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Is it posible to mock object for service? Is it posible to mock value of cfg.user.core.token? Im mocking httpBackend like this:

```
   $httpBackend.when("GET","/check/").respond({
                data: ['success']
              });
```

This is my code:

```
.service("session", function ($window, $location, $http, cfg) {
        var service = {};
        service.check = function () {
            $http.get("/chceck/" + cfg.user.core.token).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data && response.data.success !== true) {
                    service.logout();
                }
            });
        };
    return service;
})
```

my part of test:

```
it("check ", function () {
   spyOn(session, 'check').and.callThrough();
   session.check();
   expect(session.check).toHaveBeenCalled();
   $httpBackend.flush();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cfg` is an angular constant:

```
angular.module('mymodule')
  .constant('cfg', {
    user: {
      core: {
        token: 'token'
      }
    }
  });
```

So in the Jasmine tests you can stub this constant:

```
describe('mytest', function () {
  var 
    cfgStub = {
      user: {
        core: {
          token: 'stubToken'
        }
      }
    };

  beforeEach(module('mymodule'));

  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.constant('cfg', cfgStub);
  }));

  ...
});
```

And use `cfgStub` wherever you want in the tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was helpful